# When $R/I \cong S/J$, where $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay, $S$ is regular local and $ht(J)=\mu(J)$

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, local-rings, cohen-macaulay, regular-rings

Let $(R,\mathfrak m)$ be a local Cohen-Macaulay ring. Let $I\subseteq \mathfrak m$ be an ideal of $R$. If $R/I \cong S/J$ for some regular local ring $S$ and ideal $J$ of $S$ such that
$ht(J)=\mu(J)$, then is it true that $ht(I)=\mu(I)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Try $R=k[[x,y,z]]/(x^2-yz)$ and $I=(x,y)$.